# How do I fix the '[cdkFocusInitial]' is not focusable warning, when running jest unit test of a material dialog component with cdkFocusInitial?

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-cdk

I am running jest unit test of a material dialog component, where I have `cdkFocusInitial` on an input element in the dialog. This works perfect when running the application, but when I run unit tests in Jest I get the following error:

```js
console.warn node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-a11y.umd.js:1861
    Element matching '[cdkFocusInitial]' is not focusable. HTMLInputElement {
      __zone_symbol__inputfalse: null,
      __zone_symbol__blurfalse: null,
      __zone_symbol__compositionstartfalse: null,
      __zone_symbol__compositionendfalse: null,
      __zone_symbol__focusfalse: null,
      __zone_symbol__animationstartfalse: null,
      [Symbol(SameObject caches)]: [Object: null prototype] { classList: DOMTokenList {} }
    }
```

I tried to setup jest in stackblitz to reproduce, but my component essentially look very similar to the official dialog example. I have cloned that [example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c5rvpv), and added `cdkFocusInitial`. When you open the dialog, focus is set as expected:

[image]

I hope you can help figure out what I can try to fix/remove this warning.

**Workaround**

In a beforeEach function, I mock the console.warning like this:

```js
 beforeEach(() => {
       // Removes "'[cdkFocusInitial]' is not focusable" warning when running tests
       console.warn = jest.fn();
    });
```

Comment: Hello. Have you found a solution for this? I face the same problem with Angular 9 and while running the tests with Karma and Jasmine.

Comment: Only the posted workaround, mocking the console.warn method

Answer (score 16):

You'll need to mock the `InteractivityChecker` service which is what is calling `isFocusable`.

Easiest way to do this is in your TestBed override the isFocusable method like the following:

```js
import { InteractivityChecker } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [...],
        declarations: [...],
    })
        .overrideProvider(InteractivityChecker, {
            useValue: {
                isFocusable: () => true, // This checks focus trap, set it to true to  avoid the warning
            },
        })
        .compileComponents();
}));
```

Comment: Glad I can help! Had to do a bit of digging around the source code to find out where that error was triggering from

Comment: Works great, for completeness; `InteractivityChecker` is imported from `@angular/cdk/a11y` since Intellij didn't suggest it for me.

Comment: @DauleDK This should be marked as the answer for the question

Answer (score 0):

In the case of using **[Spectator](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator)**. You need to mock `InteractivityChecker` from `@angular/cdk/a11y` package.

```
import { createHostFactory } from '@ngneat/spectator/jest';
import { InteractivityChecker } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';

const createHost = createComponentFactory({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: InteractivityChecker,
      useValue: {
        isFocusable: () => true,
      },
    },
  ],
  ...
});
```